# Need assistance in insert statement

Tags: sql

I have a table with 4 columns

```
+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  |
+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D1 |
| A3 | B3 | C3 | D1 |
+----+----+----+----+

SELECT @a = A
    ,@b = B
    ,@c = C
    ,@d = D
FROM TABLE
WHERE D = D1

SELECT @rot = @@rowcount

SET @i = 1
```

now i want to insert the above selected values into a new table .

When I am using the below condition I am able to insert only 1st row data 3 times. How can I insert all 3 rows into new table

```
WHILE @i < @rot
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #table
    VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d)

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Please let me know if there is any option to insert all 3 rows from the select statement

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try instead of using `@@ROWCOUNT` and the WHILE loop, since its going to only return the rows where your desired condition is met anyway.

```
SELECT *
INTO #table
FROM tbl
WHERE D = 'D1'
```